# Jquery Datatable functions not working properly after reload

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using **Jquery Datatable** for my plugin.
Below is the code sample:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tab-per" ).DataTable();
});

$(function() {
    var form = document.getElementById("postme");
    $('form#postme').on('submit', function(e) {
            $.post('cnp.php?hal=103.sv', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
            alert('Data perusahaan sukses disimpan !');
            $( "#tab-per" ).load( "cnp.php?hal=103 #tab-per" );
            $( "#tab-per" ).DataTable();
            form.reset();
            // This is executed when the call to mail.php was succesful.
            // 'data' contains the response from the request
            }).error(function() {
            alert('Mohon maaf ada kesalahan')
            // This is executed when the call to mail.php failed.
           });
          e.preventDefault();                   
    });
});
```

The problem is, datatable pagination and search is not working anymore when I click the submit button to save data to my database after the table gets refreshed.

Comment: any error you are getting in console  ? ?

Comment: you can try this if its works. 
$( "#tab-per" ).fnDraw();  instead of $( "#tab-per" ).DataTable(); after submitting the form

Comment: @PunitGajjar no there is no error in my console but when i change $( "#tab-per" ).fnDraw(); instead of $( "#tab-per" ).DataTable(); 

this is the error i got :

cnp.php?hal=103:217 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fnDraw is not a function(anonymous function) @ cnp.php?hal=103:217l @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4c.fireWith @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4k @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:6(anonymous function) @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:6

Comment: @DenyRachmat Check if your AJAX response is proper and all required JS files are included

Comment: @sid i think what's wrong with my code when i using .load() function, it only executing #tab-per id of my table, so i think that code ignoring my datatable function :(

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
 var tab-per-table;
 $(function() {
    tab-per-table=$(function() {
        $( "#tab-per" ).DataTable();
    });
 });
//when you post success,you can delete.$( "#tab-per" ).DataTable(),just do:
 tab-per-table.draw();
```

Comment: fndraw just for datable,so you must let the datatable data to the 'table-per-table',hope it help;

Comment: Thanks for reply im sorry but i have using that way and it give me error fnDraw not a function :(

Comment: however,we can use it,but if 'error', replace the 'fnDraw()' with 'draw()',look this:[link](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw())